# Gradle plugin for Tomcat 10 With Spring Boot 3 and Spring Security 6

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, build.gradle, war

I was earlier using Spring Boot 2.6.6 and Tomcat 8. Now I upgraded to Spring Boot 3.1.3 and Spring Security 6. The plugin used earlier was `com.bmuschko:gradle-tomcat-plugin:2.7.0` but it has support till Tomcat9x.

Now Spring Boot 3 does not use below Tomcat 10x. I tried using cargo plugin but it requires either local or remote tomcat.

I want to use embedded tomcat10 with spring boot 3 and execute similar gradle task `tomcatRunWar`